# Local LAMP Problem

Tags: php, apache, lamp, bitnami

I installed LAMP via the Bitnami installer. I am able to go to the Bitnami index screen and navigate to phpMyAdmin just fine, but I cannot seem to get my .php files to run. I know that Apache is installed because I keep getting errors saying "such and such is not on the server".

Here is what I am typing to get a simple .php "hello world" file up:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/home/username/Documents/hello_world.php

Thanks!

Comment: You should copy your file to "htdocs" folder...

Comment: As a first step I would place "hello_world.php" in your www folder and access it from 127.0.0.1:8080/hello_world.php

Comment: have you check your hello_world.php are in the apache folder ?

Comment: where is htdocs or apache folder at? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a clarification on the BitNami LAMPStack. The default htdocs folder is placed in /apache2/htdocs.